# Bash Jq parse json string

Tags: json, linux, bash, ubuntu, jq

I've to call a file and pass a json as parameters in this way
(suppose that my file is called test.sh), from bash I need to do something like this:

```
./test.sh "[{\"username\":\"user1\",\"password\":\"pwd1\",\"group\":\"usergroup1\"},{\"username\":\"user2\",\"password\":\"pwd2\",\"group\":\"usergroup2\"},{\"username\":\"user3\",\"password\":\"pwd3\",\"group\":\"usergroup3\"}]"
```

and the content of test.sh is the following

```
#!/bin/bash

#read the json
system_user="$1"

printf "$system_user"

accounts=($(jq -s ".[]" <<< $system_user))

printf "$accounts"

for account in "${accounts[@]}"
do
  printf "\n\n$account\n\n"
done
```

the output of -> printf "$system_user"  is

```
[{"username":"user1","password":"pwd1","group":"usergroup1"},{"username":"user2","password":"pwd2","group":"usergroup2"},{"username":"user3","password":"pwd3","group":"usergroup3"}]
```

but the output of -> printf "$accounts" is something like this

[
[
{
"username":
"user1"
etc. etc. one object for each token :-(

and so on, but what I was expecting is an array of three object (like you can test on jqplay.org)

```
 {
   "username": "user1",
   "password": "pwd1",
   "group": "usergroup1"
 }
 {
   "username": "user2",
   "password": "pwd2",
   "group": "usergroup2"
 }
 {
   "username": "user3",
   "password": "pwd3",
   "group": "usergroup3"
 }
```

In this way I can make a foreach on ${accounts[@]}

What I'm doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: `jq '.[]' <<< "..."` (without the `-s`) gives you the output you want; you might want to consider why you think you need a `bash` array to hold that in the first place. Depending on what you want to *do* with the data, you  may be able to do it directly in `jq`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `-c` option, you can print each JSON object on a single line, making it easier to populate the array you want.

```
$ readarray -t arr < <(jq -c '.[]' <<< "[{\"username\":\"user1\",\"password\":\"pwd1\",\"group\":\"usergroup1\"},{\"username\":\"user2\",\"password\":\"pwd2\",\"group\":\"usergroup2\"},{\"username\":\"user3\",\"password\":\"pwd3\",\"group\":\"usergroup3\"}]") 
$ printf "Object: %s\n" "${arr[@]}"
Object: {"username":"user1","password":"pwd1","group":"usergroup1"}
Object: {"username":"user2","password":"pwd2","group":"usergroup2"}
Object: {"username":"user3","password":"pwd3","group":"usergroup3"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are interchanging bash arrays and JSON arrays. When you are creating `accounts` array, bash splits the elements per each whitespace. That's why you don't get what you expect. You can try the following:

```
declare -A accounts

while IFS="=" read -r key value
do
    accounts[$key]="$value"
done < <(jq -r "to_entries|map(\"\(.key)=\(.value)\")|.[]" <<< $system_user)

for account in "${accounts[@]}"
do
    printf "$account\n"
done
```

(stolen from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26717401/328977)

to get the following output:

```
{"username":"user1","password":"pwd1","group":"usergroup1"}
{"username":"user2","password":"pwd2","group":"usergroup2"}
{"username":"user3","password":"pwd3","group":"usergroup3"}
```