# Structure solution in bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a string which is comming from API request, that looks like big json each element have 2 fields(name, href), after this action I added this name to array:

```
str_from_api="$(user_groups_json "limit=100" | jq -r '.items | .[].name')"
readarray -t usergroups_array <<< "$str_from_api"
```

But I need to store 2 variables(name and href) in array usergroups_array. I mean next solution:

Array:

```
str_from_api=(name:"Test name", href: "Test href")
```

This array will be long with 100 records. After I need to do operations with each name and each href, that is why I need access to each element of this structure.

How can I implement this?

## UPDATE

json:

```
{
 "totalCount": 2,
 "items": [
     {
      "name": "test name",
      "active": false,
      "createdFrom": "SAML",
      "_meta": {
        "allow": [
        "DELETE",
        "GET",
        "PUT"
       ],
       "href": "https://href2.com"
  }
},
{
  "name": "test name 2",
  "active": false,
  "createdFrom": "SAML",
  "_meta": {
    "allow": [
      "DELETE",
      "GET",
      "PUT"
    ],
    "href": "https://href1.com"
  }
}
]
```

Comment: Can you post example text stored in `str_from_api` ? Like 5 lines or so.

Comment: @KamilCuk I added for you

Comment: Bash doesn't have nested structures like that. I think you're using the wrong language for this job.

Comment: @Barmar it's not my dicision, just need some help in this, are you sure, that bash can't do this?

Comment: Keep it in JSON and use `jq` to extract what you need.

Comment: @Barmar after this code, I used loop for getting each name from this json, after I had action, after this action I need to get href for concrete name, how can I do this?

Comment: Can you use an associative array? `([name 1]: "href 1", [name 2]: "href 2", ...)`?

Comment: Your sample is not valid JSON.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717277/converting-a-json-object-into-a-bash-associative-array for example

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty attempt at getting your output in a Bash loop.

```
user_groups_json "limit=100" |
jq -r '.items | .[] | (._meta.href + " " + .name)' |
while read -r href name; do
    echo "'$name' has href '$href'"
    : do stuff with these variables here
done
```

You say you want these in an array, but then explain that you wish to process them one at a time; so storing the whole list in a variable which you only access once seems superfluous.

Comment: I want to work with names, and if names has some symbols, I need to send href which connect to this name

Comment: I don't understand if that is a question, a comment indicating that this answer is what you need, or a comment indicating that this answer doesn't do what you want.

Comment: thanks, you are right, it does what I need and what I asked