# Loop through json variable

Tags: json, bash, zsh, jq

I have a json variable which looks like this:

```
{
  "status": "closed",
  "host": "host1-availabe_zone_A"
}
{
  "status": "closed",
  "host": "host2-availabe_zone_B"
}
{
  "status": "closed",
  "host": "host3-availabe_zone_A"
}
```

I am trying to convert it to a hash-like data structure (associate array in zsh/bash) to get number of hosts in each availabe zone. The preferred result will be this based on the data above:

```
availabe_zone_A -> 2
availabe_zone_B -> 1
```

I got some problem when trying to iterate the json variable.

```
declare -A az_to_number_of_open_hosts
for host in $(jq . <<<  $hosts_list)
do
  az=$(rev <<< $(echo $host | jq .host) | cut -d. -f3 | rev)
  ((az_to_number_of_open_hosts[$az]++))
done
```

The line to extract available zone is because the host format is always `blabla123213.az.domain.com`.
The code does not work since it seems the variable `host` refers to each line of json string rather than a json entry. Is there a recommended way to iterate each json entry?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. If you have multiple objects they have to be contained in an array so you can loop through it.

Comment: What are you expecting `jq .` to do? It just returns the input as its output.

Comment: Why do you declare `az_to_number_of_open_hosts` and not use it?

Comment: @Barmar Isn't it a valid json? since jq works pretty well with the entries above:

`jq .host /tmp/test.json
"host1-availabe_zone_A"
"host2-availabe_zone_B"
"host3-availabe_zone_A" `

Comment: seems the format does not work in comment :(. I use `echo` just want to show it only prints each line of string. And yes, I will do some extraction to extract the available zone from the `.host` and use it as a key of the associate array

Comment: @Barmar update the code as your comment. Hope it makes sense to u

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717277/converting-a-json-object-into-a-bash-associative-array][1]

Comment: `jq` can iterate over a *stream* of separate JSON values, which is what you have.

Answer (score 1):

You're just counting values in your json. Split out the part you want to count

```
$ jq -nr 'inputs.host/"-"|last' input.json
availabe_zone_A
availabe_zone_B
availabe_zone_A
```

then you could either group and count:

```
$ jq -nr '[inputs.host/"-"|last]|group_by(.)[]|"\(.[0]) -> \(length)"' input.json
availabe_zone_A -> 2
availabe_zone_B -> 1
```

https://jqplay.org/s/g_8HgqiQ1o

or iterate the values tallying as you go:

```
$ jq -nr '
reduce (inputs.host/"-"|last) as $k ({}; .[$k] += 1)|to_entries[]|"\(.key) -> \(.value)"
' input.json
availabe_zone_A -> 2
availabe_zone_B -> 1
```

https://jqplay.org/s/S2oeLfMRNR

Answer (score 0):

Use `.host` to get the `host` properties.

```
$ hosts_list='  {
    "status": "closed",
    "host": "host1-availabe_zone_A"
  }
  {
    "status": "closed",
    "host": "host2-availabe_zone_B"
  }
  {
    "status": "closed",
    "host": "host3-availabe_zone_A"
  }'
$ for host in $(jq -r '.host' <<<  "$hosts_list")
do
 echo "$host"
done
host1-availabe_zone_A
host2-availabe_zone_B
host3-availabe_zone_A
```

Use the `-r` option to make it output raw strings, rather than JSON strings surrounded by double quotes.

And don't forget to quote variables unless you deliberately need word-splitting and wildcard matching to be done on the value.

Comment: This does not provide a solution to the stated problem (as it exists right now). Also, if the user just wished to print the key names, there would still be no need to use a shell loop. –

Comment: @peak he edited the question after I wrote the answer, originally it just printed them. That was presumably just a simplification of what he really wanted to do with the names.

Comment: Yes, that is why I included the parenthetical remark.

Answer (score 0):

With the following in program.jq:

```
# bag of words
def bow(stream): 
  reduce stream as $word ({}; .[($word|tostring)] += 1);

bow(inputs | .host | sub("^.*-availabe";"availabe"))
```

the invocation:

```
jq -n -f program.jq input.json
```

produces

```
{
  "availabe_zone_A": 2,
  "availabe_zone_B": 1
}
```

If you really want the output in the STRING --> N format,
add -r to the command-line options, and add the following
two lines to program.jq:

```
| to_entries[]
| "\(.key) --> \(.value)"
```

### Comments

1. You might want to fix the spelling ("available" vs "availabe")
2. As this example illustrates, jq can handle an input stream consisting of JSON entities -- i.e. a stream of JSON.