# JSON Sub-Array to Bash Associative Arra

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have this JSON with measurement data:

```
{
 "errorCode":0,
"statusDataInfo":{
  "function-status-text-005":{
     "textValue":"2006-0310",
     "type":"basic-text"
  },
  "function-status-text-027":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":"50"
  },
  "function-status-text-049":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":""
  },
  "function-status-text-025":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":"43"
  },
  "function-status-text-047":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":""
  },
  "function-status-text-068":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":"0"
  },
  "function-status-text-009":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":"22"
  },
  "function-status-text-007":{
     "textValue":"2006-0325",
     "type":"basic-text"
  },
  "function-status-text-029":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":""
  },
  "function-status-text-041":{
     "textValue":"2006-0960",
     "type":"basic-text"
  },
  "function-status-text-063":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":"3"
  },
  "function-status-text-060":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":"67"
  },
  "function-status-text-023":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":""
  },
  "function-status-text-045":{
     "textValue":"2006-0300",
     "type":"basic-text"
  },
  "function-status-text-021":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":""
  },
  "function-status-text-043":{
     "textValue":"2006-0300",
     "type":"basic-text"
  },
  "function-status-text-065":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":"0"
  },
  "function-status-text-015":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":"0"
  },
  "function-status-text-037":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":"1550"
  },
  "function-status-text-058":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":"163"
  },
  "function-status-text-013":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":"22"
  },
  "function-status-text-035":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":"11.22"
  },
  "function-status-text-019":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":""
  },
  "function-status-text-017":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":"24"
  },
  "function-status-text-039":{
     "textValue":"2006-0940",
     "type":"basic-text"
  },
  "function-status-text-051":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":""
  },
  "function-status-text-056":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":"0"
  },
  "function-status-text-011":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":"22"
  },
  "function-status-text-031":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":"19"
  },
  "function-status-text-053":{
     "type":"simple-value",
     "value":"-"
      }
   },
   "statusBackgroundDataInfo":{
  "0xA0":{
     "value":"0"
  },
  "0x20":{
     "value":"0"
  },
  "0xE1":{
     "value":"0"
  },
  "0xE0":{
     "value":"1"
  },
  "0xFA":{
     "value":"0"
  },
  "0xF0":{
     "value":"1"
  },
  "0x80":{
     "value":"1"
  },
  "0xF9":{
     "value":"1"
  },
  "0xC4":{
     "value":"0"
     }
  }
}
```

And what I want is a bash associative array made out of it, where I can just access the values from the JSON like this:

```
myArray[function-status-text-005][type]
myArray[function-status-text-005][value]
```

I tried many solutions from Stackoverflow and the web, but I cannot get any to work.
Any help would be appreciated

kind regards

**EDIT**

I tried the solution [in this Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717277/converting-a-json-object-into-a-bash-associative-array) but it does not work. It needs a top level array, while mine is neatens in `statusDataInfo`

**EDIT2**
Thanks to @Cyrus I got a step further:

```
jsonValues=$(cat data.json | jq -r '.statusDataInfo | to_entries|map("\(.key)=\(.value)")|.[]')

for i in "${!jsonValues[@]}"
do
  echo "key  : $i"
  echo "value: ${jsonValues[$i]}"
done
```

ready into an assoc array BUT it has only one key with the corresponding value holding all info from the json:

```
key  : 0
value: function-status-text-005={"textValue":"2006-0310","type":"basic-text"}
function-status-text-027={"type":"simple-value","value":"50"}
 function-status-text-049={"type":"simple-value","value":""}
 function-status-text-025={"type":"simple-value","value":"43"}
 function-status-text-047={"type":"simple-value","value":""}
 function-status-text-068={"type":"simple-value","value":"0"}
 function-status-text-009={"type":"simple-value","value":"22"}
 function-status-text-007={"textValue":"2006-0325","type":"basic-text"}
 function-status-text-029={"type":"simple-value","value":""}
 function-status-text-041={"textValue":"2006-0960","type":"basic-text"}
 function-status-text-063={"type":"simple-value","value":"3"}
 function-status-text-060={"type":"simple-value","value":"67"}
 function-status-text-023={"type":"simple-value","value":""}
 function-status-text-045={"textValue":"2006-0300","type":"basic-text"}
 function-status-text-021={"type":"simple-value","value":""}
 function-status-text-043={"textValue":"2006-0300","type":"basic-text"}
 function-status-text-065={"type":"simple-value","value":"0"}
 function-status-text-015={"type":"simple-value","value":"0"}
 function-status-text-037={"type":"simple-value","value":"1550"}
 function-status-text-058={"type":"simple-value","value":"163"}
 function-status-text-013={"type":"simple-value","value":"22"}
 function-status-text-035={"type":"simple-value","value":"11.22"}
 function-status-text-019={"type":"simple-value","value":""}
 function-status-text-017={"type":"simple-value","value":"24"}
 function-status-text-039={"textValue":"2006-0940","type":"basic-text"}
 function-status-text-051={"type":"simple-value","value":""}
 function-status-text-056={"type":"simple-value","value":"0"}
 function-status-text-011={"type":"simple-value","value":"22"}
 function-status-text-031={"type":"simple-value","value":"19"}
 function-status-text-053={"type":"simple-value","value":"-"}
```

Comment: Post those efforts into the question!

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717277/converting-a-json-object-into-a-bash-associative-array) what you're looking for?

Comment: I thank you for this comment. Unfortunately I tried this and it and it produces an empty output (the solution you linked needs a top-level array, while mine is nested)

Comment: Are `textValue` and `value` present along with `type`? They could occur inter related?

Comment: When  `"type"="basic-text"`then you have a `textValue`. In the other cases you have a `value`

Comment: This might help: `jq -r '.statusDataInfo | to_entries|map("\(.key)=\(.value)")|.[]' file`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I edited my question with your hint. The problem is, that this command does not create the correct keys in the array but instead makes an array with one key (0) and the value holds the complete info from the json

Comment: bash arrays are one-dimensional.

Comment: In the future, please post the minimal amount of data that illustrates the problem. Wouldn't less than 10 lines of data been sufficient to demonstrate your problem? Good luck.

Comment: Save yourself a *lot* of trouble: choose a language other than `bash` that supports real data structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> myArray[function-status-text-005][type]
>
> myArray[function-status-text-005][value]
>
> I tried many solutions from Stackoverflow and the web, but I cannot get any to work

That's because bash does not support that kind of indexing, as illustrated by the following:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
5.0.7(1)-release
$ declare -A ary
$ ary["a"]=("x" "y z")
bash: ary["a"]: cannot assign list to array member
```

For "workarounds" and alternatives, see e.g.

[Multi-dimensional arrays in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233825/multi-dimensional-arrays-in-bash)

Since your data has only two "types", you might want to consider one of the simplest options: having two associative arrays.  So instead of writing:

```
myArray[function-status-text-005][type]
```

you'd write something like:

```
type[function-status-text-005]
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, `bash` does not support 2-dim array. Then how about having
two arrays: `type[]` and `value[]`.
Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A type value
pat='^(.+)=\{"([^"]*)":"([^"]*)","([^"]*)":"([^"]*)"\}'
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $pat ]]; then
        key="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        if [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} = "type" ]]; then
            type[$key]="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
            value[$key]="${BASH_REMATCH[5]}"
        else
            type[$key]="${BASH_REMATCH[5]}"
            value[$key]="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
        fi
    fi
done < <(jq -r '.statusDataInfo|to_entries|map("\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)")|.[]' file.json)

# show the contents of the arrays
for i in "${!type[@]}"; do
    printf "%s = %s, %s\n" "$i" "${type[$i]}" "${value[$i]}"
done
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: To the downvoter: I'd appreciate if I can hear your frank opinion why you felt unconfortable with my answer for my future reference. BR.