# Convert JSON from AWS SSM to environment variables using jq

Tags: json, regex, environment-variables, jq

I have done some research on this and feel as if I'm about 80% there but struggling to adjust the jq output as required due to splitting one of the strings.

I'm trying to convert the JSON output from AWS SSM to environment variables.

AWS command

```
aws ssm get-parameters-by-path \
--path /qa/es \
--with-decryption \
--query 'Parameters[*].{Name:Name,Value:Value}' \
```

Output

```
[
    {
        "Name": "/qa/es/AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID",
        "Value": "ABC123"
    },
    {
        "Name": "/qa/es/AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY",
        "Value": "abcdefghijkl"
    },
    {
        "Name": "/qa/es/ENDPOINT",
        "Value": "https://amazonaws.com"
    }
]
```

My required output from jq, note I'm only after the environment variable AFTER the last /. There may be cases where this could be /qa/es/something/nested/ENV_VAR

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=ABC123
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=abcdefghijkl
ENDPOINT=https://amazonaws.com
```

Once I have this I can utilise the answer here to set the environment variables. [Exporting JSON to environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48512914/exporting-json-to-environment-variables/48515341?noredirect=1#comment84051241_48515341)

The closest I have got is

```
jq -r "map(\"\(try(.Name |= split(\"/\")))=\(.Value|tostring)\")|.[]" params.json
```

Which gives me

```
{"Name":["","qa","es","AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],"Value":"ABC123"}=ABC123
{"Name":["","qa","es","AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],"Value":"abcdefghijkl"}=abcdefghijkl
{"Name":["","qa","es","ENDPOINT"],"Value":"https://amazonaws.com"}=https://amazonaws.com
```

Close, but not close enough! Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the -r command-line option,

```
.[]
| "\(.Name|split("/")|.[-1])=\(.Value)"
```

yields:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=ABC123
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=abcdefghijkl
ENDPOINT=https://amazonaws.com
```

This seems to correspond to what you've asked for, but this approach has the potential disadvantage that it assumes something about "=", so please be careful!

Answer (score 1):

As the previous comment but use '@sh' to escape the value

```
| "\(.Name|split("/")|.[-1])=\(.Value | @sh)"
```