# Use jq to parse json into environment variable format

Tags: json, environment-variables, jq

I would like to below code to output
`KNOCK_KNOCK="Who is there?"`

```
TEST_FILE='{
  "KNOCK_KNOCK": "Who is there?"
}'
for s in $(echo $TEST_FILE | jq -r "to_entries|map(\"\ 
(.key)=\(.value|tostring)\")|.[]" ); do
    echo $s
done
```

I got the loop from this post: [Exporting JSON to environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48512914/exporting-json-to-environment-variables)

and cannot figure out how to modify to get my expected output.  The problem seems to be the spaces in the .value

For the following test case I get the expected results:

```
TEST_FILE='{
  "KNOCK_KNOCK": "Whoisthere?",
  "POSTGRES_URI": "postgress://user:pass@testdb.com",
  "WILL": "I.AM"
}'
for s in $(echo $TEST_FILE | jq -r "to_entries|map(\"\(.key)=\ 
(.value|tostring)\")|.[]" ); do
    echo $s
done

KNOCK_KNOCK=Whoisthere?
POSTGRES_URI=postgress://user:pass@testdb.com
WILL=I.AM
```

---

I went with the following solution, which works for me, but the accepted answer is ok.

```
TEST_FILE='{
  "KNOCK_KNOCK": "Who is there?"
}'
echo $TEST_FILE | sed 's_[{}]__'| sed 's_: _=_' | sed 's_  _export _'
```

Comment: I just went ahead and used sed replacement instead, and works for me.  But thanks Friedrich for you answer, that works as well!

Answer (score 4):

One of many possibilities:

```
jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key,.value] | join("=")' <<< "$TEST_FILE"
```

It would probably be advisable to use `@sh` as well:

```
$ echo $'{"KNOCK_KNOCK": "Who \'is\' there?"}'
  | jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key,(.value|@sh)] | join("=")'
KNOCK_KNOCK='Who '\''is'\'' there?'

$ KNOCK_KNOCK='Who '\''is'\'' there?'
$ echo "$KNOCK_KNOCK"
Who 'is' there?
$
```

Note also that if you are going to use `$TEST_FILE`, the double-quotes might be necessary.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the quotes are only necessary to work around various bugs in here-string handling in earlier versions of `bash`. 4.3 (and to a greater extent 4.4) appears to have resolved those problems, allowing the here string to be left unquoted.

Comment: For anyone using this answer, note that quotes aren't escaped.

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it but you can do this without a loop with this line:

```
$ echo '{"KNOCK_KNOCK": "Who is there?"}' | jq -r 'to_entries[] | .key + "=\"" + (.value|tostring) + "\""'
KNOCK_KNOCK="Who is there?"
```

### Explanation

`to_entries` transforms your object to an array of objects like this:

```
$ echo '{"KNOCK_KNOCK": "Who is there?"}' | jq -r 'to_entries'                   
[
  {
    "key": "KNOCK_KNOCK",
    "value": "Who is there?"
  }
]
```

You can then take each array element with the `[]` and use the `key` and `value` field to do simple string concatenation using the `+` operator.