# How can I convert JSON to an environment variable file format?

Tags: json, bash, shell, environment-variables, jq

I am fetching a AWS Parameter Store JSON response using the AWS cli:

```sh
echo $(aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --with-decryption --region eu-central-1 \
  --path "${PARAMETER_STORE_PREFIX}") >/home/ubuntu/.env.json
```

This outputs something like:

```json
{
  "Parameters": [
    {
      "Name": "/EXAMPLE/CORS_ORIGIN",
      "Value": "https://example.com"
    },
    {
      "Name": "/EXAMPLE/DATABASE_URL",
      "Value": "db://user:pass@host:3306/example"
    }
  ]
}
```

Instead of writing to a JSON file, I'd like to write to a `.env` file instead with the following format:

```
CORS_ORIGIN="https://example.com"
DATABASE_URL="db://user:pass@host:3306/example"
```

How could I achieve this? I found similar questions like [Exporting JSON to environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48512914/exporting-json-to-environment-variables), but they do not deal with nested JSON / arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy with `jq` and some string interpolation and `@sh` to properly quote the Value strings for shells:

```
$  jq -r '.Parameters[] | "\(.Name | .[rindex("/")+1:])=\(.Value | @sh)"' input.json
CORS_ORIGIN='https://example.com'
DATABASE_URL='db://user:pass@host:3306/example'
```

Comment: You can redirect the output to whatever file you want, of course. And you can pipe the `aws` output directly to `jq` instead of using an intermediate file if desired.

Comment: Glad you added the `@sh` filter you initially missed. An alternate `jq` command syntax that does the same: `jq -r '.Parameters[] | (.Name | split("/")[-1])+"="+(.Value | @sh)' input.json` i find clearer than escaping parenthesis

Comment: I always forget there are ones other than `@csv` until I see them in the manual.

Comment: Anyway found this question is a dupe.

Comment: Wonder if I should post this on that one too (I realized that the variable name can be extracted without a `split()` like I originally had and all the answers there also use)...