# Ansible : how to get te extra-vars in a docker container

Tags: ansible, environment-variables, ansible-awx

From an Ansible playbook via AWX I want to start a docker container, which performs data analysis.
Since the data analysis is rather complex there are a lot of parameters, that I need to give to the container.
To do so I defined a survey in AWX and use the extra-vars in the API calls.

Since I have a lot of parameters (11 survey questions, 2 of them as multiple choice multiselect)
its rather tedious to convert every single one into a boolean/string and have an environment variable for it.
Here is an example how this would look like:

```yaml
- name: "Run Container"
  community.docker.docker_container:
    image: "{{ docker_image }}"
    env:
      Var1: "{{ Var1_from_survey | string }}"
      Var2: "{{ Var2_from_survey | string }}"
      VarN: "{{ VarN_from_survey | string }}"
```

My idea was to get all extra vars from Ansible via something like `"{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname] }}"`
and then save them as one environment variable in the container, where I can use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48513046/10020441)
to split them apart.

But it seems that there is no way in Ansible to get all extra-vars in a compacted way.
There is no way with `"{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname] }}"` to know which vars are from the survey and which are from Ansible itself.

Do you know what is the best way to transfer a lot of extra-vars from the survey (or API) to a docker container?

Comment: rather than individual variables can your survey define items in a dict?

Comment: There's no way to get out of the box a dictionary/list of `extra_vars` passed on the command line. See [this related question](/q/72937001) for possible workarounds.