jq not printing full string with spaces in Bash script
Here is my structure:

I am trying to print some values in a JSON file. Here is the service-data.json:
{
    "service_name": "nphies-support.service",
    "description": "nphies-support-service Spring Boot Application",
    "user": "aceusr",
    "working_directory": "/home/aceusr/deployment/nphies/nphies-support",
    "java_home": "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-21.0.1",
    "jar_file": "nphies-support-service.jar"
}

I am reading this JSON in a bash script using jq:
#!/bin/bash

echo "$0 script starting"

# test if the jq is installed
test_json=$(echo "{ }" | jq)
if [ "$test_json" != "{}" ]; 
then
    echo "jq not installed"
    exit 1
fi

#read json into variable json
json=$(cat service-data.json)

#converting json objects to bash variable
declare $(echo $json | jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | "export \(.key)=\(.value)"')
echo "service_name = $service_name"
echo "description = $description"
echo "user = $user"
echo "working_directory = $working_directory"
echo "java_home = $java_home"
echo "jar_file = $jar_file"

#use the -r option to output the result as raw text, without quotes. 
description1=$(echo $json | jq -r '.description')
echo "description1 = $description1"

exit 0 

This JSON is an object so I am using declare function to convert JSON into bash script variables.
For description it is only printing nphies-support-service instead of nphies-support-service Spring Boot Application. Looks like it is breaking on first space.
But when I read the same field using the syntax name=$(echo $json | jq -r '.description') it prints the whole text.

Why is it not printing the whole text in iteration? What do I do so it prints whole text for description variable?

json=$(cat service-data.json); 1) no need for this, just pass it as arg to jq: jq 'some-filter' service-data.json

echo $json is itself buggy.

BTW, "export \(.key)=\(.value)" has serious security problems. Always use the @sh filter in jq to shell-quote strings before dumping them into a context where they'll be evaluated as code.

...you don't want "description": "Prevent users from injecting $(rm -rf ~) or '$(rm -rf ~)' into commands" to actually run rm -rf ~

Beyond that, declare export doesn't make sense. If you want everything to be exported, make it declare -x -- take out the export.

...looking back again, that failure to use @sh is the immediate cause of your problem -- it's not making it clear that the spaces that are data need to be literal data rather than syntax.

@CharlesDuffy Thanks for the reply. As I said I am new to script and jq both. It's just a start. After getting the values I will create a systemd service with these values. Here I am just making sure that I am getting the correct values so in the service all work well. I am not getting the @sh thing. can you provide some link so I can take a look at it. Thanks

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69502302/14122 for an example of using @sh. BTW, you might consider trace logging (bash -x yourscript or putting set -x within that script's text) to be useful here to get a view of what's going on at runtime.
