# jq to_entries string and number cannot be added

Tags: json, jq

I'm not understanding how `to_entries` works in jq.

I have the following json payload in `payload.json`

```
{"REGION":"us-east-1","EMAIL":"contain","UPDATE":1}
```

which I want to convert into `=` delimited keypairs, like so;

```
REGION=us-east-1
EMAIL=contain
UPDATE=1
```

I was using

```
jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | .key + "=" + .value' < payload.json
```

But I get an error

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): string ("UPDATE=") and number (1) cannot be added
```

If I understand correctly, the issue is that the update value is a number, not a string (ie, having them not match types is an issue) so I tried the following, both with the same error;

```
string interpolation:
jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | (.key) + "=" + (.value)' < payload.json

tostring:
jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | .key + "=" + .value|tostring' < payload.json
```

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378013/how-to-convert-a-json-object-to-key-value-format-in-jq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what am I missing?

A pair of parentheses:

```
.key + "=" + ( .value|tostring )
```

Alternatively, you could use string interpolation, e.g.

```
"\(.key)=\(.value)"
```

Comment: It never occured to me to combine them, but yep works like a charm. I'll accept as soon as I can, thanks!