# How can I use jq to remove quotes from key names and remove braces?

Tags: json, jq

I'm interested in transforming from json format to tfvars using `jq`, i.e.:

Input:

```
{
  "foo": "aaa",
  "bar": "bbb",
}
```

Desired output:

```
foo = "aaa"
bar = "bbb"
```

I tried

```
echo "{\"foo\": \"aaa\",\"bar\": \"bbb\"}" | jq '.[]'
"aaa"
"bbb"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a JSON object to key=value format in jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378013/how-to-convert-a-json-object-to-key-value-format-in-jq)

Comment: It's pretty close, but the quoting is a little bit off: echo "{\"foo\": \"aaa\",\"bar\": \"bbb\"}" | jq 'to_entries|map("\(.key) = \(.value|tostring)")|.[]'
"foo = aaa"
"bar = bbb"

Comment: You need to invoke jq with the `-r` flag to get rid of quotes. Still doesn't match the expected output, but close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A modification of the earlier answer might work.

```
jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key) = \"\(.value)\""'
```

Answer (score 1):

The tfvars specification is hard to come by, but numbers should not be quoted, `null` is a special case, and arrays are also allowed as values, e.g. https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/google-cloud-platform-variables?in=terraform/gcp-get-started gives the following as an example:

```
cidrs = [ "10.0.0.0/16", "10.1.0.0/16" ]
```

So the following should be closer to a general solution:

```
jq -r '
  def q:
    if type | IN("string", "boolean") then "\"\(tostring)\"" 
    else .
    end;
  to_entries[] | "\(.key) = \(.value|q)"
'
```