# Print a JSON array in human readable format using jq

Tags: json, formatting, jq

I am relatively not experienced in `jq`, so the answer may be very simple, but I couldn't find it on the Internet somehow.

I have a JSON array like this:

```
[
 {
  "key1": "value1a",
  "key2": "value2a",
  "key3": "value3a",
  "keyn": "valuena"
 },
 {
  "key1": "value1b",
  "key2": "value2b",
  "key3": "value3b",
  "keyn": "valuenb"
 },
 {
  "key1": "value1z",
  "key2": "value2z",
  "key3": "value3z",
  "keyn": "valuenz"
 }
]
```

And I want to print it in the following "human-readable" format:

```
key1 : value1a
key2 : value2a
key3 : value3a
keyn : valuena

key1 : value1b
key2 : value2b
key3 : value3b
keyn : valuenb

key1 : value1z
key2 : value2z
key3 : value3z
keyn : valuenz
```

using preferably `jq` command.

Note that the number of elements of the array and the number of key/value pairs for each element is variable and not known in advance.

Comment: Does this help? [How to convert a JSON object to key=value format in jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378013/how-to-convert-a-json-object-to-key-value-format-in-jq)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That's almost 90% in the right direction. The only missing part is: How can I add an empty line between different array elements?

Comment: Okay, let me post an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind an empty line at the end of the output, this should work fine:

```bash
jq -r '.[] | (to_entries[] | "\(.key) : \(.value)"), ""'
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ZnKl3RO7Qur)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid the extra newline is to use `join` twice:

```
[.[]
 | [ (to_entries[] | "\(.key) : \(.value)}") ]
   | join("\n")]
| join("\n\n")
```